# Improve ffmpeg parallel procesing processing

Tags: performance, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert a series of images and an audio file to video.
This process happens in parallel, i.e, for different sets of images and audio file, I am spawning ffmpeg process in parallel.
For a single request, ffmpeg response time is around `20 seconds`, which degrades to around `80 seconds` [avg] for 1000 req. I am using 30 as throttle limit.
`preset` is `veryfast`. Can anyone  suggest ways to improve ffmpeg performance?

**Update:**

Please find below **configuration** used:

`CPU : 16 * 3.00 GHZ
Ram : 32 gb
OS: Win Server 2012`

**ffmpeg command:**

`ffmpeg -f concat -i <path to text file containing images sequence> -i <path to audio file> -y -filter_complex_script <path to filter script file> -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset veryfast <output.mp4>`

Comment: What's your command?

Comment: What’s your OS?

Comment: What's your hardware?

Comment: Hi. I have updated the question.